# It is possible to create an MQTT tag?

Tags: support

It is possible to create the MQTT tag?

There are some questions about MQTT but not a tag...

Description from stackoverflow tag:

> MQTT - a light on the wire protocol for publish/subscribe. Clients and servers in various languages, C, Python, Erlang, C#, Java and Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Tags for specific technologies, like a protocol, is almost always a good idea. (When it comes to more vague concepts, more care might be needed in tag creation, but that is not the case here.)

I took the liberty of creating the tag right away, and tagging a few questions with it. When you gain 300 in reputation you will be allowed to create new tags on your own.